# How do I make my iterator classes not look like container classes?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, googletest

### The premise

Say I have a container class `Box` which provides inner classes `const_iterator` and `iterator`. Because I want an `iterator` to be castable to a `const_iterator`, the latter inherits from the former:

```
class Box {
  // ...
public:
  class const_iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, const int> { /* ... */ };
  class iterator : public const_iterator { /* ... */ };
  // ...
};
```

### The problem

Now I want to test these classes using Google Test. Let's assert that the `begin()` and `end()` don't return the same thing:

```
const Box a;
EXPECT_NE(a.begin(), a.end());
```

Say hello to a compile error:

- clang: `no member named 'begin' in 'Box::const_iterator'`
- g++: `‘const class Box::const_iterator’ has no member named ‘begin’`

### The cause

Some research led me to [this template](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h#888) in the Google Test source code (follow the link for expanded documentation):

```
typedef int IsContainer;
template <class C>
IsContainer IsContainerTest(int /* dummy */,
                            typename C::iterator* /* it */ = NULL,
                            typename C::const_iterator* /* const_it */ = NULL) {
  return 0;
}
```

The result of this template magic is that if arguments to `EXPECT_*` have `iterator` and `const_iterator` member classes, then the type is assumed to be a container class. Knowing this, Google Test can print pretty human-readable reports when expectations fail, which is nice.

However, there's this little detail:

```
// Note that we look for both C::iterator and C::const_iterator.  The
// reason is that C++ injects the name of a class as a member of the
// class itself (e.g. you can refer to class iterator as either
// 'iterator' or 'iterator::iterator').  If we look for C::iterator
// only, for example, we would mistakenly think that a class named
// iterator is an STL container.
```

so if I understand things right, this means that

- `Box::const_iterator` has itself as a member class named `const_iterator`, and `std::iterator` as a memberclass named `iterator`.
- `Box::iterator` has itself as a member class named `iterator` and `Box::const_iterator` as a member class named `const_iterator`.

Therefore both my iterator classes look like container classes to Google Test!

### The question

How do I design my iterator classes to make them not look like containers?

Things I've tried:

- Declaring the `std::iterator` superclass of `const_iterator` as `private`. This solves the problem for `const_iterator` by hiding the `iterator` member class, but it still doesn't let me pass `a.begin()` as a parameter to `EXPECT_NE` unless `a` is `const`. Seems like Google Test uses `iterator begin()` rather than `const_iterator begin() const` for some reason.
- Removing the `std::iterator` superclass altogether. Is this a bad idea? I suppose I'll have to declare my `std::iterator_traits` manually, is there anything else I'll lose by not extending `std::iterator`?
- Declaring the `Box::const_iterator` superclass of `Box::iterator` as `private`. This may or may not be an option since I'd have to redeclare methods I'd rather want to reuse (such as `operator++`).

Is there anything else I've overlooked?

---

### The example

```
#include<iterator>
#include <memory> //unique_ptr<T>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class ThreeInts {
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> v;

  public:
  ThreeInts() : v(new int[3]) { v[0] = 0; v[1] = 1; v[2] = 2; };
  ThreeInts(int val) : ThreeInts() { v[0] = val; v[1] = val; v[2] = val; };

  bool operator==(const ThreeInts& other) const {
    return v[0] == other.v[0] && v[1] == other.v[1] && v[2] == other.v[2];
  }

  class const_iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, const int> {
  protected:
    int* p;
  public:
    explicit const_iterator(int* p) : p(p) {}
    const_iterator& operator++() { ++p; return *this; }
    bool operator==(const const_iterator& rhs) const { return p == rhs.p; }
    bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rhs) const { return p != rhs.p; }
    int operator*() const { return *p; }
  };

  class iterator : public const_iterator {
  public:
    explicit iterator(int* p) : const_iterator(p) {}
    int& operator*() const { return *p; }
  };

  iterator begin() { return iterator(v.get()); }
  iterator end() { return iterator(v.get()+3); }
  const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(v.get()); }
  const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(v.get()+3); }
};

TEST(ThreeInts, ThisTestCompilesAndPrettyFailureMessagesAreShown) {
  const ThreeInts a(1), b(2);
  ThreeInts c(1), d(2);
  EXPECT_EQ(a, b);
  EXPECT_EQ(a, c);
  EXPECT_EQ(c, d);
}

TEST(ThreeInts, ThisTestCompilesIfTheStdIteratorParentIsPrivate) {
  const ThreeInts a;
  EXPECT_NE(a.begin(), a.end());
}

TEST(ThreeInts, ThisTestAlsoCompilesIfTheStdIteratorParentIsPrivateButItIsAHassle) {
  ThreeInts a;
  ThreeInts::const_iterator beg = a.begin();
  ThreeInts::const_iterator end = a.end();
  //EXPECT_NE(beg, end); // Compile error unless the std::iterator superclass is private
}

TEST(ThreeInts, ThisTestDoesNotCompileEvenIfTheStdIteratorParentIsPrivate) {
  ThreeInts a;
  //EXPECT_NE(a.begin(), a.end());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Name your iterator class `ThreeIntsIterator` or something - just not `iterator`. In `ThreeInts`, do `typedef ThreeIntsIterator iterator;`

Comment: The google test `IsContainerTest` is garbage - simple typedef(s) make no container - better is a test for the member functions `begin()` and `end()`, which has shortcomings, too

Comment: You didn't understand that comment right. It looks for both `C::iterator` and `C::const_iterator` because if it were only to look for the former, then `C` might simply be `iterator` but not a container with sub-type `iterator`.

Comment: Btw, use `std::array<int,3>` instead of `ThreeInts` and you don't have to worry about defining the `iterator` etc.

Comment: @Walter the `ThreeInts` used here is of course just a toy example. I came across the issue while working on a school assignment where you implement your own `std::vector`-like container.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that does indeed seem to work! A bit ugly, but definitely an option.

Comment: I would recommend filing a bug against Google Test. Clearly `EXPECT_NE` should never call `begin()` or `end()` on its arguments unless it can *prove* that they exist. And even that is questionable. This kind of template magic is a wonderful source of time consuming, subtle bugs - the Google people should made aware of the nonsense that their code attempts to do.

Comment: You have your inheritance backwards. If A inherits from B, A is convertible to B, not the other way around.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, and it'd be good if an `iterator` (A) could be converted into a `const_iterator` (B), no?

Comment: Um, sorry, that's me being apparently unable to read. Your inheritance direction is right. Or at least the code is right. The description seems wrong as it does not correspond to the code.

Comment: There are some problems in `iterator` inheriting `const_iterator`. Consider for instance `operator++`. You want to reuse it, but what does it return? Yes, a `const_iterator&` in both cases. This is not correct and will possibly break standard algorithms. Same is true for `+` and `-` you will want to implement. Better implement both iterator classes separately (possibly inheriting from a common parent using CRTP) and provide a conversion operator.

Comment: @n.m. Very good points. Seems like separate implementations is the way to go, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThreeInts::iterator` should not inherit from `ThreeInts::const_iterator`, instead they should be implemented separately.

```
class ThreeInts::iterator : public std::iterator< std::random_access_iterator_tag, int> { ... }
class ThreeInts::const_iterator : public std::iterator< std::random_access_iterator_tag, const int> { ... }
```

The problem seems to be that otherwise `ThreeInts::const_iterator` both has members named `const_iterator` and `iterator` (aka the constructors). Also making the `iterator` inherit from `const_iterator` is not const-correct as the `const_iterator` should only hold a pointer/similar to `const` data. STL containers also keep the two iterators separate.

In that code, it would probably be sufficient to instead of defining iterator classes, simply define

```
using iterator = int*;
using const_iterator = const int*;
```

Comment: You're right in that `const_iterator` should only hold `const` data, that detail had slipped me by. But couldn't I still have `iterator` inherit from `const_iterator` and just override the `const` data with non-`const` data? I'll have to try that out when I have the time. Thanks also for your suggestion to keep them separate. Now, a correction: the magic template used in gtest explicitly states `typename`, so the issue is that the classes embed themselves as members, not the constructors. Also, please don't get distracted by the implementation details of my `ThreeInts` example.